# Do we call $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ discontinous and non differentiable at $ x = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Do we call $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ discontinous and non differentiable at $ x = 0$ ??

Because the function has the domain as $ x ≥ 0 $ , so we cannot have a LHL for it. So do we call the function continuous or not ?? Is it also differentiable or not as similarly LH Derivative won't exist ??

I'm in highschool, so this might be bit weird , but I got confused , because, many a times, we say (for people who are just getting started ) that a function is continuous if you can make its graph without lifting the pen. So now , to graph it I can draw it without lifting the pen , but the formal definition is that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^+} f(x+h) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-} f(x+h) = f(x) $

Comment: I have to be the guy to say this: there are continuous functions any piece of whose graph you can't draw at all, let alone without lifting your pen. But this function is continuous.

Comment: @MattSamuel But what about LHL and differentiablity ?? As there is no LHL and for continuity, we need to have LHL = RHL = f(x)... ?

Comment: The domain does not include the left hand side, so there's no limit to take there.

Comment: Oh okay, so if there is no left hand side,. You simply don't take the LHL, I think then differentiablity should also follow the same ? Thank You so much !!:)

Comment: This would actually be called an endpoint discontinuity, so it is discontinuous at x=0.

Comment: "f a function is described to have a closed endpoint on its interval, it is called an endpoint discontinuity. The limit cannot exist at the endpoint, however, because the limit needs to view function values as xx approaches from both of its sizes. "

Comment: Limits are not defined by taking limits from both sides. You have to first be able to take a limit from each side to even consider them in the first place. If it doesn't make sense to take a limit from the left side, then all you need to do is take the limit from the right side. @N.Bar

Comment: If it doesn't "make sense" to take a LHL, then the limit doesn't exist. If the limit doesn't exist, the point can't be continuous.

Comment: @N.Bar As I like to say, why not say the limit doesn't exist because it doesn't exist from the fruity side? What is this "fruity side" you may ask? Simply something that is extremely out of context for the function in question. In any case, I give examples of actual things that make this harder to deal with in my answer below: complex numbers or higher dimensions, which don't have an ordering over which taking limits can be done in a left/right fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, limits are not handled by considering a "left" side and a "right" side. The definition of the limit stated in words is something like this:

> We say that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that we can make $f(x)$ and $L$ within $\epsilon$ of each other for all values of $x$ **in the domain of** $f$ that are within $\delta$ of $a$.

Symbolically: $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L\iff\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\operatorname{Dom}(f)[0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon]$.

See also: [$(\epsilon,\delta)$-definition of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_and_related_statements)

Provided that the domain of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ containing both sides of a neighborhood of $a$, this means we must consider the limit from the left as well as the right.

Without the restriction that we only consider the domain of $f$, you might end up considering many different values of $x$. For example, what if $x$ were a complex number? What if it was a 3-dimensional vector? Suddenly, the notion of "left" and "right" become very hard to make use out of. Instead, we make use of the notion of "distance", and from there we define limits.

Continuity is then defined as follows:

> $f$ is said to be continuous if, for every $a$ in the domain of $f$, we have $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, otherwise it is called discontinuous.

And for differentiability:

> The derivative of $f$ at $a$ is defined as $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$ if it exists, otherwise it is non-differentiable at $a$.

For your given example, all of these conditions are met, so it is both conditinuous and differentiable.

---

And as two more caveats:

- limits to points which cannot be approached from the domain of $f$ are undefined e.g. $\lim\limits_{x\to-1}x^{3/2}$, but if you can approach the point from within the domain of $f$, then you can have a limit, even if $f(a)$ isn't defined.
- for continuity, we do not look at points outside of the domain of $f$ or limits to points outside the domain of $f$. So even if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, but $f(a)$ doesn't, we wouldn't call that a discontinuous function. An example of such is $1/x$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+1%2Fx+continuous%3F) seems to give both sides to the $1/x$ being continuous or not. It says:

$\frac1x$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$.

$\frac1x$ is continuous on its domain.

Though generally we don't consider functions outside of their domain.

Comment: Wait a second... But in the comments as @N.Bar points out that this is called as end point discontinuity and the function should be discontinuous and non differentiable at the end point....and looking it up online also tells that if you can't approach from both sides its discontinuous.....

Comment: @DivMit As I stated in my answer, "Provided that the domain of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ containing both sides of a neighborhood of a, this means we must consider the limit from the left as well as the right." That is to say, *if it makes sense to consider the left and right sided limits*, then we must consider them. But if it doesn't make sense to consider them, then we simply don't. You wouldn't say $f$ is discontinuous because $\lim\limits_{x\to\heartsuit}f(x)$ doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Thank You Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you define continuity or differentiability. If you define it only on open intervals, then no.

However, there's usually no reason to make such a restriction and we may allow a function to be continuous at a point if the limit exists as one approaches the point in all possible ways (in this case just one), and this limit coincides with the value of the function there. Then in this case the function is both continuous and differentiable at $x=0.$ Indeed, applying the rules formally, you get that $$(x^{3/2})'=\frac 32 \sqrt x,$$ which vanishes when $x=0.$ So there's a finite value for the derivative calculated formally. Also, taking the limit formally yields no problems. Thus we can make life convenient for ourselves.

But again, as a final word, it depends on how much restrictions we placed on ourselves in the first place. It's eventually always up to us.

Comment: "If you define it only on open intervals, then no." Could you elaborate?

Comment: Are you implying that you are using points outside the domain of $f$ to justify the limit not existing? If so do you have a reference for where you saw this definition?

Comment: An interesting open interval is all positive x. Now are you saying the function is not differentiable then? Indeed, please explain.

Comment: I have yet to see such a definition. Again, do you have a reference for such? Most texts and such that I have looked at would agree on things such as $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt x=0$. Indeed, as you say, "there's usually no reason to make such a restriction". So why would you even consider it at all?

Comment: What is so crazy about $[0,\infty)$? And I think that talking about something with such uncertainty is likely only going to cause more confusion than help.

Comment: I thing the discussion is becoming pointless now, but one fair question is asked: Reference. Do you have that?

Comment: The function is both continuous and differentiable at $x=0$. Full stop.

This matter of open vs. closed intervals is irrelevant.

Comment: It is unfortunate but true that in North American calculus books, they make this distinction of continuity inside an open interval vs. continuity at endpoints; and further, differentiability is defined only at points inside an open interval.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Any particular examples? I live in North America, and I don't recall having seen such a definition in my calculus textbooks.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Larson/Edwards, Calculus of a single variable (10th ed.) p. 70 vs p. 73; Stewart, Calculus (3rd ed.) pp. 80-82.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Interesting, though I was honestly hoping for more motivation for this kind of definition by reading where one might it. Thank you nonetheless.